# Most efficient way to get last initial?

Tags: php

I'm working on a custom forum. It will use an email and password to log in, and the forum will display your first name and last initial. The database stores their first name and full last name.

What would be the easiest way to make it abbreviate the last name to an initial?

It currently uses this to display full name:

```
$name = $row['user_firstname'] . " " . $row['user_lastname'];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 $name = $row['user_firstname'] . " " . $row['user_lastname'][0];
```

Just add `[0]` to the end to get the first character.

Answer (score 1):

And to make it prettier:

$name = ucfirst(strtolower($row['user_firstname'] )). " " . ucfirst($row['user_lastname'][0]);

so MYFIRSTNAMe lastName still shows as MyfirstnameL